# Center header, title and description when minimizing browser

Tags: css, html, centering

trollsirl.blogspot.com When I minimize my browser my website's title is all the way to the right. How do I make my title centered when my browser is minimized?

```
.Header.description {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 50%;
    right: -96%;
    transform: translate(100%, 180%);
}

h1 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5%;
    left: 183%;
    right: -430px;
    bottom: 10px;
    transform: translate(10%, 50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use media queries or body size, look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp). Create a css that centeres the header when size is small, for example with `margin: 0 auto` in the specific class.

Comment: Can you help me with that? Sorry I am having trouble.

Comment: Look at the link i posted bellow. Read it and try it cause on this way u will learn. Thats better cause u can adapt it on youre project much better!